# problemas em usar fail no junit

Tags: java, testes-de-unidade, junit

Eu quero cria mensagem personalizadas para cada erro de exceção na minha classe de teste, o meu teste está funcionando perfeitamente, porém quando eu gero propositalmente um erro ele não entra dentro da minha exceção como podem ver abaixo;

```
try {
    error.checkThat(tipoIndicioService.getPorId(1), is(tipoIndicio));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Assert.fail("O valor do tipo indicio que está no arquivo CSV não existe no banco de dados");
}
```

Eu iniciei ela através do `ErrorCollector` assim como mostra abaixo;

```
@Rule
public ErrorCollector error = new ErrorCollector();
```

como faço para cair na exceção?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1 -** Para realizar o que você deseja, basta passar a mensagem no `checkThat` dessa forma:

```
error.checkThat("O valor do tipo indicio que está no arquivo CSV não existe no banco de dados", tipoIndicioService.getPorId(1), is(tipoIndicio));
```

O primeiro parâmetro é justamente o motivo da falha. Você não precisa fazer esse controle manualmente.

**2 -** Os asserts não lançam uma exceção quando falham, eles lançam um Error. Para cair no catch você tem que fazer isso:

```
catch (Error e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Assert.fail("O valor do tipo indicio que está no arquivo CSV não existe no banco de dados");
}
```

O fato de poder fazer, não quer dizer que você deveria. Pra o seu caso eu acho que não precisa.

**3 -** Por último, no seu caso específico, mesmo se você colocar o `catch(Error)`, o erro não vai cair no `catch` porque o `checkThat` não lança esse erro. A ideia desse `ErrorCollector` é justamente continuar o teste mesmo depois que uma falha for encontrada.

Se você executar o código abaixo, onde não estamos utilizando o `ErrorCollector`, vai perceber que a mensagem "Test" não será exibida e o erro será capturado no `catch`:

```
try {
    Assert.fail();
    System.out.println("Test");
} catch (Error e) {
    System.out.println("O valor do tipo indicio que está no arquivo CSV não existe no banco de dados");
}
```

Já no código a seguir, estamos usando o `ErrorCollector`. Nesse caso, mesmo falhando no teste, o fluxo continua e a mensagem "Test" será exibida. Porém, o erro não será capturado no `catch`, porque o `checkThat` não o lança.

```
try {
    error.checkThat(1, is(2));
    System.out.println("Test");
} catch (Error e) {
    System.out.println("O valor do tipo indicio que está no arquivo CSV não existe no banco de dados");
}
```